# Deploy Jingo to Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

When I try to deploy a jingo repo to Heroku, the app fails to launch. I investigated the logs using `heroku logs -a myapp` and discovered that the fatal error occurs during the construction of the Git object in the lib/gitmech.js script. Specifically it fails when the constructor tries to call fs.statSync(gitDir) with: `Error ENOENT, no such file or directory /app/.git`.

An [issue on the github repo](https://github.com/claudioc/jingo/issues/100) for jingo mentions this problem and the issue has been closed with the comment that heroku doesn't support jingo because of its ephemeral file system.

I have tried to edit the gitmech.js to escape fs.statSync(gitDir) and set the pushInterval to 0, thinking that the flaw could be avoided by not pushing/pulling to the remote repo. But it appears that git is centrally connected to how jingo indexes, stores and searches pages.  Not just how it manages the repository.

Any ideas for how to get jingo to deploy to Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to arise due to the method through which heroku-cli deploys code to Heroku. The .git sub-folder does not get added to the remote file system, so fs.statSync(gitDir) fails to find the .git sub-folder. And jingo fundamentally does not work without git.

Last night, I discovered a workaround to this problem. I have not yet tried to edit the wiki and I'm pretty sure that push/pull will not function without setting up an ssh key to connect to the remote origin. But, as a static site, here's how to deploy Jingo to Heroku:

**1. Modify Jingo configuration:**

*Either* in config.yaml specify:

```
application:  
    repository: '/app'
```

*or*
in lib/config.js (for a more dynamic solution) specify:

```
application:  
    repository: __dirname + '/../'
```

**2. Create Procfile for app in root:**

```
web: node jingo -c config.yaml
```

**3. Install Heroku plugin [heroku-builds](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds):**

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
```

**4. Modify heroku-builds code:**

remove "--exclude .git" from

~/AppData/Local/heroku/plugins/node_modules/heroku-builds/commands/builds/create.js (Win 7+)

*or*

~/heroku/plugins/node_modules/heroku-builds/commands/builds/create.js (Linux)

**5. Deploy code using heroku-builds from root:**

```
heroku builds:create -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME
```